# ResourceDictionaries Causing Problems to Other controls

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I have two resource dictionaries and trying to add in

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/MainSkin.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/Expander.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

if i try to add converters in resources then it will not find the dictionaries.

Comment: Greater detail needed, where are you adding the converters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/MainSkin.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/Expander.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then you are assigning that specific ResourceDictionary to the UserControl.Resources property. If you want to add additional resources, outside the merged dictionaries, you have to add them to the ResourceDictionary like so:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
   <ResourceDictionary>
         <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/MainSkin.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Skins/Expander.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <!-- TODO: Add items here -->
    </ResourceDictionary>
    <!-- NOTE: You can't add items here -->
</UserControl.Resources>
```